# Output HTML Table to the Body of an Email using object with property that's an array

Tags: powershell, html-table

I can create a nice table using my object for an email HTML body, but one of the properties contains an array and it's showing as "System.object[]". I'm trying to get that to display its contents as well, but can't figure it out.

**Current output results look like**

```
ServerName ServerEvents
Server-P1 | No events found
Server-P2 | system.object[]
```

**My object looks like**

```
ServerName ServerEvents
Server-P1  "No events found"
Server-P2  EVENT1, EVENT2, EVENT3
```

---

```
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 4px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #0085cc;color: white}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 4px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
"@

$TableOutput = $Global:FinalResults.foreach({[PSCustomObject]$_}) | select 'ServerName','ServerEvents' |ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header |Out-String
```

Comment: Use `Select -ExpandProperty ServerName,ServerEvents`

Comment: This gave me an error: "Cannot convert 'system.object[]' to the type 'system.string' required by parameter 'ExpandProperty'. The specified method is not supported.

Comment: Try `Select-Object ServerName,@{N='ServerEvents';e={$_.ServerEvents -join ', '}}`

Comment: I apologize, I was wrong about the format of my object. The ServerEvents are listed one on top of the other, with a space in between. I tried using your format with a space and received the same error. I checked and it is a system array type.

Comment: As an example, when I do finalresults.serverevents each event is listed on its own line one after the other.

Comment: I removed -expandproperty and left in "Select-Object ServerName,@{N='ServerEvents';e={$_.ServerEvents}}" and it appears to work! Any idea how to add a space between the ServerEvents?

Comment: @LotPings You should post your solution as an answer so I can give you credit bro.